# How to retrieve bridging headers that has been lost

Tags: swift, xcode

I was trying to put a facebook login in my app. I'm also checking some of the tutorials that'll help me to do this. Then i have created a header file that i also delete since that i wasn't able to accomplished the tutorial that i'm watching. Then all of a sudden, i'm having an error that stating...

> Briding Header 'Users/mac/Desktop/App
>   Files/myApp/myApp-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist

I don't know why is that happening. I try to delete my .swift file and replace it with the same name then it still having an error. I even try to make a .swift file with a different name but still having an error as well.

Comment: Go to the path and again copy it. if that is not there in the path so make a new bridging-header.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani, i'm just a new user of xcode/swift here. I just want to ask, what will i put in the bridging-header file after a make a new one?

Answer (score 0):

In build settings.. in “Swift Compiler -Code Generation”—> Objective-C Bridging Header — “reset the Path of Bridging header file”

How to create a Swift Bridging Header Manually

- Add a new file to Xcode (File > New > File), then select “Source” and
  click “Header File“.
- Name your file “YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”. Example: In my
  app Station, the file is named “Station-Bridging-Header”.
- Create the file.
- Navigate to your project build settings and find the “Swift Compiler
  – Code Generation” section. You may find it faster to type in “Swift
  Compiler” into the search box to narrow down the results. Note: If
  you don’t have a “Swift Compiler – Code Generation” section, this
  means you probably don’t have any Swift classes added to your project
  yet. Add a Swift file, then try again.
- Next to “Objective-C Bridging Header” you will need to add the
  name/path of your header file. If your file resides in your project’s
  root folder simply put the name of the header file there. Examples:
  `“ProjectName/ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”` or simply
  `“ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”`.
- Open up your newly created bridging header and import your
  Objective-C classes using #import statements. Any class listed in
  this file will be able to be accessed from your swift classes.

Comment: i deleted it and try to run it but i'm having a new error saying, "Apple Mach-O Linker Error"

Comment: you need add your  Bridging Header and import library that linker error.

Comment: step to add bridging header in swift http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/